# Grouping as.factors together in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have data that I want separated for a linear model into three separate groups. The data ranges from 0 to 60. The way the data is spread, I want the 0's, 60's and then the rest in-between as the last group. I have used I(as.factor(data)==0) and same for 60 to separate those two but how do I have the rest of the data. The length of the data is not the same so just putting the rest into another object doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. First we have to create some data. We'll call it `dta` since `data` is the name of a function:

```
dta <- c(25, 60, 60, 59, 60, 0, 19, 0, 0, 60, 60, 0, 22, 0, 59, 60, 
          0, 0, 60, 0, 60, 57, 10, 60, 55, 0, 60, 45, 3, 0)
```

Now create a variable that groups the data the way you want:

```
grp <- factor(ifelse(dta==0, 1, ifelse(dta==60, 3, 2)))
```

You can get fancier if you want:

```
grp <- factor(ifelse(dta==0, "0", ifelse(dta==60, "60", "Between")), 
     levels=c("0", "Between", "60"))
table(grp)
# grp
#       0 Between      60 
#      10      10      10
```